# Angular build failure when creating production build

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am having a below error while running the `ng build --prod` this is compile work for `ng build` and `ng server`

ERROR in ng:{path}/dashboard/promotions/add-promotion/promotion-form.component.html (33,13): Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

```
ERROR in ng:{path}/dashboard/promotions/add-promotion/promotion-form.component.html (33,13): Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

ERROR in ng:{path}/dashboard/promotions/add-promotion/promotion-form.component.html (45,13): Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

ERROR in ng://{path}/dashboard/promotions/add-promotion/promotion-form.component.html (45,13): Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
```

Below is my component form builder and the html

```
 this.promotionForm = this.fb.group({
      'id':[null],
      'title': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50),
        Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'), Validators.required,Validators.minLength(1)])],
      'description': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      'imageSrc': [null, [Validators.required]],
      'contactPerson' : this.fb.group({
                          'name': [null, [Validators.required]],
                          'email': [null, [Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/)]],
                          'phone': [null, [Validators.required,
                            Validators.pattern(/^[0-9]{10}$/)]]
                        }),
    });
```

Html for the component

```
<form [formGroup] ="promotionForm" (submit)="submit(promotionForm.value)">
  <--Top Form fields-->
  <table class="full-width" cellspacing="0">
    <tr >
      <div formGroupName="contactPerson">
        <td >
          <md-input-container class="full-width">
            <input mdInput
                   formControlName="name"
                   placeholder="Sales Person" [ngModel]="promoData?.contactPerson.name"
                   [formControl]="promotionForm.controls['name']">
            <div *ngIf="!promotionForm.controls.contactPerson.controls.name.valid
                            && (promotionForm.controls.contactPerson.controls.name.dirty)">
              <span class="primary">Please enter a valid name.</span>
            </div>
          </md-input-container>
        </td>
        <td>
          <md-input-container class="full-width">
            <input mdInput formControlName="phone"
                   placeholder="Mobile Number" [ngModel]="promoData?.contactPerson.phone"
            [formControl]="promotionForm.controls['phone']">
            <div *ngIf="!promotionForm.controls.contactPerson.controls.phone.valid
                            && (promotionForm.controls.contactPerson.controls.phone.dirty)">
              <span class="primary">Please enter a valid phone number.</span>
            </div>
          </md-input-container>
        </td>
        <td>
          <md-input-container class="full-width">
            <input mdInput formControlName="email"
                   placeholder="Email Address" [ngModel]="promoData?.contactPerson.email">

            <div *ngIf="!promotionForm.controls.contactPerson.controls.email.valid
                            && (promotionForm.controls.contactPerson.controls.email.dirty)">
              <span class="primary">Please enter a valid email.</span>
            </div>
          </md-input-container>
        </td>
      </div>
    </tr>
  </table>
....</form>
```

Comment: this might help https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6099

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I checked this link, however they don't have explain answer for this,I am bit confused with it

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you shouldn't access controls like that, this is what you should do :

change

```
 promotionForm.controls['name']
```

to

```
 promotionForm.get('name')
```

and change

```
  promotionForm.controls.contactPerson.controls.phone
```

to

```
 promotionForm.get('contactPerson.phone')
```

find others and fix them as well.

Comment: Thank you for the response, compilation issue fixed with this, but validation messages are not showing

Comment: That would be another question my friend.

Comment: everything worked properly in development mode, when I switch to prod mentioned issue came, now leads to another, do you know how to solve that?